# JavaScript – Call a function of the prototype from another prototype function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to write a simple slider using plain JavaScript. As these are my first steps using the prototype of an object & following an object oriented approach in general, I am quite confused sometimes, so please bear with me.

Here is what I have:

```
function MySlider(noOfSlides, startSlide){
    this.noOfSlides = noOfSlides;
    this.startSlide = startSlide;
    this.currentSlide = this.startSlide;
}

MySlider.prototype.nextSlide = function(){
    this.currentSlide++;
    console.log(this.currentSlide);
    return this.currentSlide;
};

MySlider.prototype.startSlider = function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        MySlider.nextSlide();
    }, 2000);
};

var slides = new MySlider(4, 1);

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    slides.startSlider();
}, false);
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working, after the 2 seconds wait because of `setInterval`, I get the following error: `TypeError: MySlider.nextSlide is not a function`.

While I understand what the problem is, I don't know what to change. I already tried it with `this.nextSlide()` but that didn't work either. My guess is that it has something to do with the prototype chain, but I am still trying to understand this.

How to solve this problem? Or is it a bad idea in general to it this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: *"My guess is that it has something to do with the prototype chain"* No, not at all. If you want to learn more about `this`, I recommend to read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: @FelixKling I understand that you are fed up with repeating questions, I was just unable to find *your* answer using the search. I just gave you an upvote, great info! Especially the mention of common names as `that` and `self` are great as it helps to understand scripts written by others.

Comment: No worries, I'm not blaming you :) I know that it is not always easy to find the right question/answer to a problem. But that's why we have the ability to close vote. It just doesn't make sense to repeat the same solution over and over again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to preserve the context (the value of `this`) when you set up the timer handler:

```
MySlider.prototype.startSlider = function(){
    var slider = this;
    setInterval(function(){
        slider.nextSlide();
    }, 2000);
};
```

By saving the value of `this`, you ensure that when the interval timer goes off it'll be able to invoke the "nextSlide" function in the context of the correct object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its working! But why can't I simply use `this.nextSlide();`?

Comment: @Sven because the value of `this` is determined upon each function call. When the system (the JavaScript runtime) calls your timer handler function, it does not know what value to use for `this`. Functions in JavaScript do not maintain any sort of "strong" permanent relationship to objects (like the prototype object, in this case).